# Bringing back scheduled chat - Meet the Pros

Tags: discussion, scheduled-chat, chat

A little over 2 years ago when we entered public beta, to drive traffic to the site and engage our *then* avid users we came up with the idea of scheduled chats where we picked an active "celebrity" in the Blender community, invited them to a chatroom and bombarded them with fun and interesting questions for an hour or so.

Granted this quickly failed for several reasons.

- the site didn't have active moderators back then so we had to have a super mod sit in the room
- we didn't have enough people participating (had to beg people from other rooms to join :)
- timezones

With us becoming a permanent member of StackExchange and having a very active community and many chat regulars it's a good time for this to resurface. The two events we had were very successful and informative, we had Jonathan Williamson (author at CGCookie) and Campbell Barton (main Blender developer) lend us their time. Find the transcripts here [scheduled-chat](/questions/tagged/scheduled-chat).

To bring this back better than before, here's what we want to know

- who should we interview next?
- thoughts as to how to make this a regular thing, <strike>weekly</strike> every last friday interviews anyone?
- what we can do to ensure this becomes a thing and encourage our community to participate.
- should we center these around a theme, have different segments or just pop questions on the fly etc?

Comment: Interview next (for starters): Andrew Price, Gleb Alexandrov, Ton Rosendaal

Comment: making it weekly event will most likely kill it , you will run out of "Celebrities" and regular audience and interest

Comment: Great point, evey last friday could work. Mike Pan is my nominee for now.

Comment: Greg Zaal, Reynante Martinez maybe? Every last friday would be good.

Comment: @Chebhou I wonder if we could have different off-week programming, to keep up interest . . .

Comment: @TARDISMaker Good one with Greg. I thought about Reynante but couldn't be bothered to look up his name since I was in a hurry

Comment: Ton would be cool.  @Chebhou [is right](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/bringing-back-scheduled-chat-meet-the-pros?cb=1#comment4216_983) too, we definitely should do it monthly, not weekly.

Comment: I'd say that if we do a theme for the interviews, it should be rather loose. Also, a few more suggestions, Andy Goralczic, Sebastian Konig. I'm trying to think of people who would give a bit more variety. Also, Kent Trammel?

Comment: In addition to those mentioned... Brian Savery of Pixar who is heading the development of Renderman for Blender, Brecht Van Lommel or any of the present Cycles devs (or just any Blender devs really), Blender open project artists (support Gooseberry!), Enrico Cerica who is well known for his work with Blender+Octane, CynicatPro who has been bringing a lot of PBR knowledge to the Blender community, or developers of major add-ons such as Blend4Web or Sverchok.

Comment: [Pierrick Picaut](https://www.artstation.com/artist/pieriko) anyone?

Comment: I'd be interested in chat with @TroyJamesSobotka and Sebastian Koenig

Answer (score 6):

We could raise participation by asking the interviewee (out of the kindness of their hearts) to post/tweet/announce the interview so their fans come and visit us. Some members of our site might actually find out about it that way, since not everyone know/reads about chat & meta.

Comment: exactly the chat and the meta posts don't have that popularity

Comment: ~10 people is more than enough for one of these sessions (usual amount in chat every other day) and meta posts can be featured on the main sidebar for those extra few views. Also a good time to see if we could *possibly* launch our own site blog.

Comment: We may even get some new users this way too.  People who join to talk with so-and-so but stick around to participate on the site.