# "Meet the Pros" — Scheduled chat #3 with Mike Pan

Tags: discussion, scheduled-chat

As you may already know, we are [bringing back regular scheduled chats](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/983/599) with various blender professionals.

We are honored to have the esteemed [Mike Pan](http://mikepan.com/) as our next guest! Mike is well known in the Blender community and "dabbles" in 3D art, programming, game-making, book-writing and photography. He has over 12 years of Blender experience and a keen interest in scientific visualization

This event will be held in **[chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8923/meet-the-pros)** on

> ## Friday, January 29, 2016 at 23:00 UTC. (6:00 PM EST)
>
> We hope to see you there :)

You can browse through past scheduled chats [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8923/meet-the-pros?tab=conversations).

---

## This event has ended. You can find the transcript [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8923/meet-the-pros?tab=conversations).

Comment: Just a question, why so late?

Comment: Unfortunately it's very difficult to schedule an event like this and have it work for everyone around the globe. This time works better for people in the Americas, which is where I am at. Sorry!

Comment: @NᴏᴠɪᴄᴇIɴDɪsɢᴜɪsᴇ We should still have a small crowd, enough to get a good chat session going!